# Distributed TensorFlow - tensor content changes while sending

Tags: tensorflow

I'm writing a contrib extension to distributed tensorflow, overwriting `Rendezvous::RecvFromRemoteAsync()`. To validate my solution, I added tensor checksums in various points in the code (sender & receiver). Strangely, I see that the checksum changes while I'm still inside the send code.

So to simplify the check, I created the following function (pseudo):

**TestChecksum(Tensor t, int delay):**

```
1.  int64 checksum1 = checksum(t)
2.  usleep(delay)
3.  int64 checksum2 = checksum(t)
4.  CHECK(checksum1 == checksum2);
```

Now, I'm calling this function at the start of the `RecvLocalAsync()` callback, in the **original GRPC** code ([right here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_worker_service.cc#L335)).

For delay 100000 (micro), test passes.

For delay 200000 (micro), test fails.

Also, I checked the tensor's buffer and saw that it is shared for all step ids. So, it seems that the tensor content is being changed by another thread while  `RecvFromRemoteAsync` is still in progress. Is it possible? How do I know I receive the correct tensor?

### EDIT - How to reproduce:

Take [this](https://github.com/Mellanox/tensorflow/tree/eladw_debug_checksum_bug) branch. If you prefer, the error reproducing code is in the last commit and it can probably be cherry-picked with no conflicts.

Get [tensorflow benchmarks](https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks)

Run `tf_cnn_benchmarks.py` with at least 1 ps and 2 workers.

**The commands I used:**

```
python -u tf_cnn_benchmarks.py --job_name=ps --task_index=0 --ps_hosts=<...> --worker_hosts=<...> --server_protocol=grpc --model=resnet152 --batch_size=32 --num_gpus=2 --local_parameter_device=gpu
python -u tf_cnn_benchmarks.py --job_name=worker --task_index=0 --ps_hosts=<...> --worker_hosts=<...> --server_protocol=grpc --model=resnet152 --batch_size=32 --num_gpus=2 --local_parameter_device=gpu
python -u tf_cnn_benchmarks.py --job_name=worker --task_index=1 --ps_hosts=<...> --worker_hosts=<...> --server_protocol=grpc --model=resnet152 --batch_size=32 --num_gpus=2 --local_parameter_device=gpu
```

Comment: Could you post the TF program that you're running that reproduces this phenomenon?

Comment: @PaulTucker Thanks! Added an "how to reproduce" section to the original question.